# Apache Airflow run sub DAG

Tags: workflow, airflow

I'm starting using Apache Airflow in these days because I would like to use it for managing a quite long DAG of Tasks. Given the complexity and the thing that some task could take very long time, sometime would be very useful to run just a task or some subgraph for test purposes or because of some new data only related to these particular tasks, possibly only specifying the starting and ending task to be runnned (eg, given a DAG [a >> b >> c >> d >> e] I would like to run from 'b' to 'd' only). Is it possible with Apache Airflow to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes this is possible in airflow. What I usually do is have all tasks of the dag marked as failed or succeeded (see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/ui.html#graph-view for example) and then clear the tasks I want to run (see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/ui.html#task-instance-context-menu for example).
In your case of tasks a to e, I would clear task b with the downstream option selected and then set task e to success.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherBeck , that's an option. I was thinking to something more automatic, which cares only about the starting and the ending task of a run, but maybe there is no way to do this.